# How do I display text one at a time using razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I was learning razor pages by making a quiz app and I wanted to display questions one at a time on the site.

[This is the cshtml page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fU0L.png)

[This is the code behind --- OnGet method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMuwP.png)

[And this is the OnPost method in the code behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JveCI.png)

I'm currently displaying question in one go depending on user (how many questions they want to answer).

But I wanted to make it display questions one at a time after the user choses number of questions they want to answer

Comment: make a label , set a string (your question), once the user answers it, clear that label and change the string.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should include code in the question using code blocks, instead of pictures: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a form with multiple steps, like this:

QuizTest.cshtml.cs:

```
public class QuizTestModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public List<QnA> QnAs { get; set; }

    [BindProperties]
    public class QnA
    {
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        QnAs = new List<QnA>()
        {
            new QnA()
            {
                Question ="What's your name?"
            },
            new QnA()
            {
                Question ="Where are your from?"
            },
            new QnA(){ Question ="How old are you?" }
        };
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        var data = QnAs;
        return Page();
    } 
}
```

QuizTest.cshtml: use a hidden field to store the question and use a textbox to enter the answer.

```
@page
@model RazorAPP.Pages.QuizTestModel
 
<form asp-page ="QuizTest" id="regForm" method="post"> 
    @for(var i = 0;i< Model.QnAs.Count; i++)
    {
          <div class="tab">
            <p>Question: @Model.QnAs[i].Question.ToString() <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.QnAs[i].Question" /></p>
            <p>Answer: <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.QnAs[i].Answer"></p>
          </div>
    } 
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
      <div style="float:right;">
        <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
        <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>

        <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="step"></span> 
    </div>
</form>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}
</style>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
        showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

        function showTab(n) {
          // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
          x[n].style.display = "block";
          //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
          if (n == 0) {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
          } else {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
          }
          if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
          } else {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
          }
          //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
          fixStepIndicator(n)
        }

        function nextPrev(n) {
          // This function will figure out which tab to display
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
          // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
          if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
          // Hide the current tab:
          x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
          // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
          currentTab = currentTab + n;
          // if you have reached the end of the form...
          if (currentTab >= x.length) {
            // ... the form gets submitted:
            document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
            return false;
          }
          // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
          showTab(currentTab);
        }

        function validateForm() {
          // This function deals with validation of the form fields
          var x, y, i, valid = true;
          x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
          y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
          // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
          for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            // If a field is empty...
            if (y[i].value == "") {
              // add an "invalid" class to the field:
              y[i].className += " invalid";
              // and set the current valid status to false
              valid = false;
            }
          }
          // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
          if (valid) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
          }
          return valid; // return the valid status
        }

        function fixStepIndicator(n) {
          // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
          var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
          for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
          x[n].className += " active";
        }
    </script>
}
```

The output as below:

[image]

Reference: [How TO - Form with Multiple Steps](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp) and [Bootstrap MultiStep Form](https://codepen.io/designify-me/pen/qrJWpG).